# Android + Preferences

Tags: android

I have a `preferences.xml` and `Settings.java`... In the `onCreate` method I want to set the summary of the `preferences`... Could someone guide me what is the best way to do it???
What I know is that one way of doing is

```
activityName_text = (EditTextPreference) findPreference("activityName");
    activityName_text.setSummary(activityName_text.getText());
```

but for each key if I follow the above pattern I feel that the code will be bad...

**Preferences.xml**:

```
    <PreferenceScreen android:title="Header" >
        <EditTextPreference
            android:defaultValue="TestRequest"
            android:key="activityName"
            android:title="activityName" />
        <EditTextPreference
            android:defaultValue="Request"
            android:key="msgName"
            android:title="msgName" />

        <ListPreference
            android:defaultValue="0"
            android:entries="@array/msg_type"
            android:entryValues="@array/msg_type_values"
            android:key="msgType"
            android:title="msgType" />

        <EditTextPreference
            android:defaultValue="AA"
            android:key="senderURI"
            android:title="senderURI" />
        <EditTextPreference
            android:defaultValue="BB"
            android:key="destinationURI"
            android:title="destinationURI" />
        <EditTextPreference
            android:defaultValue="AA"
            android:key="replyToURI"
            android:title="replyToURI" />
        <EditTextPreference
            android:defaultValue="BB"
            android:key="originatorURI"
            android:title="originatorURI" />
        <EditTextPreference
            android:defaultValue="FF"
            android:key="failureReplytoURI"
            android:title="failureReplytoURI" />
        <EditTextPreference
            android:defaultValue="AA"
            android:key="correlationId"
            android:title="correlationId" />
        <EditTextPreference
            android:defaultValue="HH"
            android:key="security"
            android:title="security" />
        <EditTextPreference
            android:defaultValue="GG"
            android:key="securityType"
            android:title="securityType" />
        <EditTextPreference
            android:defaultValue="HH"
            android:key="priority"
            android:title="priority" />

        <ListPreference
            android:defaultValue="0"
            android:entries="@array/communicationPattern"
            android:entryValues="@array/communicationPatternValues"
            android:key="communicationPattern"
            android:title="communicationPattern" />
        <ListPreference
            android:defaultValue="0"
            android:entries="@array/communicationStyle"
            android:entryValues="@array/communicationStyleValues"
            android:key="communicationStyle"
            android:title="communicationStyle" />


        <EditTextPreference
            android:defaultValue="100"
            android:digits="0123456789"
            android:key="requestedBatchSize"
            android:title="requestedBatchSize" />
        <!-- radhika-number format -->
        <EditTextPreference
            android:defaultValue="78"
            android:digits="0123456789"
            android:key="batchSequenceNumber"
            android:title="batchSequenceNumber" />

        <ListPreference
            android:defaultValue="0"
            android:entries="@array/batchSequenceEndOfReply"
            android:entryValues="@array/batchSequenceEndOfReplyValues"
            android:key="batchSequenceEndOfReply"
            android:title="batchSequenceEndOfReply" />

        <EditTextPreference
            android:defaultValue="HH"
            android:key="iteratorReferenceURI"
            android:title="iteratorReferenceURI" />
        <EditTextPreference
            android:defaultValue="KK"
            android:key="fileLocationURI"
            android:title="fileLocationURI" />
        <EditTextPreference
            android:defaultValue="10/10/2010"
            android:key="timestamp"
            android:title="timestamp" />
        <EditTextPreference
            android:defaultValue="kkk"
            android:key="vendorExtensions"
            android:title="vendorExtensions" />

        <PreferenceCategory
            android:key="activityStatus"
            android:title="activityStatus" >
            <ListPreference
                android:defaultValue="0"
                android:entries="@array/activityStatusType"
                android:entryValues="@array/activityStatusTypeValues"
                android:key="actStatus"
                android:title="activityStatus" />

            <EditTextPreference
                android:defaultValue="AA"
                android:key="qualifier"
                android:title="qualifier" />
        </PreferenceCategory>


        <PreferenceCategory
            android:key="msgSpecificProperties"
            android:title="msgSpecificProperties" >
            <EditTextPreference
                android:defaultValue="multiple values"
                android:key="propName"
                android:title="propName" />
            <EditTextPreference
                android:defaultValue="multiple values"
                android:key="propValue"
                android:title="propValue" />
        </PreferenceCategory>
        <PreferenceCategory
            android:key="compressionType"
            android:title="compressionType" >
            <EditTextPreference
                android:defaultValue="kkk"
                android:key="compressionTypeAttr"
                android:title="extension" />

            <ListPreference
                android:defaultValue="0"
                android:entries="@array/compressionType"
                android:entryValues="@array/compressionTypeValues"
                android:key="compressionTypeValue"
                android:title="value" />
        </PreferenceCategory>
        <PreferenceCategory
            android:key="packingType"
            android:title="packingType" >
            <EditTextPreference
                android:defaultValue="kkk"
                android:key="packingTypeAttr"
                android:title="extension" />

            <ListPreference
                android:defaultValue="0"
                android:entries="@array/packingType"
                android:entryValues="@array/packingTypeValues"
                android:key="packingTypeValue"
                android:title="value" />
        </PreferenceCategory>
    </PreferenceScreen>
    <PreferenceScreen android:title="Body" >
        <PreferenceScreen android:title="Managed Elements" >
            <PreferenceCategory
                android:key="mdOrMlsnRef"
                android:title="md Or Mlsn Ref" >
                <EditTextPreference
                    android:defaultValue="Name"
                    android:key="rdnName"
                    android:title="rdnName" />
                <EditTextPreference
                    android:defaultValue="Value"
                    android:key="rdnValue"
                    android:title="rdnValue" />
            </PreferenceCategory>
        </PreferenceScreen>
        <PreferenceScreen android:title="Active Alarms" >
        </PreferenceScreen>
    </PreferenceScreen>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

**Settings.java:**

```
package com.example.settingstest;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.EditTextPreference;
import android.preference.ListPreference;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;


public class Settings extends PreferenceActivity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    EditTextPreference activityName_text;
    EditTextPreference msgName_text;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);  
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();       
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
        .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();        
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
        .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this); 
    }   


    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {

        Preference p = findPreference(key);
        if(p instanceof EditTextPreference)
        {           
            p.setSummary(sharedPreferences.getString(key, (String)p.getSummary()));
        }
        else if(p instanceof ListPreference)
        {           
            p.setSummary((String)((ListPreference) p).getEntry());
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Set it from the xml file itself  using android:summary="Your summary here "

Comment: I tried but its not working....dunno why :(

Comment: I will show you some code which I am using and it is working perfectly

Comment: It's kinda bad idea from the start to change summary of all items based on preference value. Summary is designed to be a description of what the preference means instead of showing the current value.

Comment: Doctoror Drive -- I feel that it depends on the usage whether to set the summary as the current preference or description abt... E.g.. For vibrate preference,the summary reflects the currect selection only as a description 4 vibrate is not reqd ...

Answer (score 0):

Use like this its always better to set summary from prefrence.xml, I am giving one example I am using this code and its working perfectly

```
<PreferenceCategory
        android:key="dbh_social"
        android:title="We know you are social" >
    <Preference
            android:key="dbh_invite"
            android:summary="Invite your friends"
            android:title="Invite Facebook Friends" />
    <Preference
            android:key="dbh_wall_post"
            android:summary="Post about us on your Facebook wall "
            android:title="Post on Facebook Wall" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
```

Comment: But using this ways... if i have edited the values in EditTextPreference, again when I launch the next time, the last changed summary will not get reflected na...

Comment: The OP wants to set the summary based on stored value, not the constant text.

Comment: So if you want handle summary dynamically then you have handle it from the code, so for that you have create instance of every prefrence and set the summary using setSummary method, Bu kinda its a bad idea but you can go through with this

Comment: @DoctororDrive-could please tell me have to set the summary of the last modified preferences in oncreate()

Comment: @Nagendra--> i wanted a generalized code such dat a loop iterates over all the keys and creates preference instances and sets the summary...

Answer (score 0):

You can put all your keys into a string-array resource and iterate over it on onCreate()

```
final String[] keys = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.keys) ; // all your keys here
SharedPreferences p = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    setPreferenceSummary(p, keys[i]);
}


private void setPreferenceSummary(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    final Preference p = findPreference(key);
    if(p instanceof EditTextPreference)
    {           
        p.setSummary(sharedPreferences.getString(key, (String)p.getSummary()));
    }
    else if(p instanceof ListPreference)
    {           
        p.setSummary((String)((ListPreference) p).getEntry());
    }
}


public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    setPreferenceSummary(sharedPreferences, key);
}
```

Comment: I thought of this one... but I have to put all the keys in the array manually... S der a way to get all keys dynamically in the code??

Comment: You can fill up the keys in string-array xml and just grab it with getResources.getStringArray(R.array.keys)
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray

Comment: Thanks 4 de suggestion... But I was thinking whether the facility to grab all de keys from xml will be in the API itself... Not sure whether getAll() will help me out...http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: It will not help if your preferences are yet empty (before the default value is modified).

Comment: Doctoror Drive ... Thanks a lot... It worked.. Just a small change p = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

Comment: I have few doubts... How to set values in summary which was not edited before in Preference... I tried using summary and DefaultValue in xml along with this code... But it did not work..